# I wrote some code to buy and sell orders but I don't know what the problem is - it keeps repeatedly taking the same orders

Tags: google-colaboratory

This is my code:

```
import yfinance as yf

# Set the ticker symbol and thresholds for support and resistance levels
ticker_symbol = "RELIANCE.NS"
support_threshold = 100
resistance_threshold = 200

# Fetch data for the ticker
ticker = yf.Ticker(ticker_symbol)

while True:
    # Get the real-time price data in 5-minute intervals
    data = ticker.history(interval="5m")

    # Calculate the recent highs and lows (support and resistance levels)
    recent_highs = data["High"][-10:].max()
    recent_lows = data["Low"][-10:].min()

    # Check if the current price is above or below the support and resistance levels
    support_level = "above" if data["Close"][-1] > recent_lows else "below"
    resistance_level = "above" if data["Close"][-1] > recent_highs else "below"

    # Take a long position if the current price is above the support level and below the resistance level
    if support_level == "above" and resistance_level == "below":
      alice.place_order(transaction_type = TransactionType.Buy,
                    instrument = alice.get_instrument_by_symbol('NSE', 'INFY'),
                    quantity = 1,
                    order_type = OrderType.Market,
                    product_type = ProductType.Delivery,
                    price = 0.0,
                    trigger_price = None,
                    stop_loss = None,
                    square_off = None,
                    trailing_sl = None,
                    is_amo = False,
                    order_tag='order1' )
      print("long")
    # Take a short position if the current price is below the support level or above the resistance level
    elif support_level == "below" or resistance_level == "above":
      alice.place_order(transaction_type = TransactionType.Sell,
                    instrument = alice.get_instrument_by_symbol('NSE', 'INFY'),
                    quantity = 1,
                    order_type = OrderType.Market,
                    product_type = ProductType.Delivery,
                    price = 0.0,
                    trigger_price = None,
                    stop_loss = None,
                    square_off = None,
                    trailing_sl = None,
                    is_amo = False,
                    order_tag='order1' )
      print("short")
    
    # Print current price, support level, and resistance level every 5 minutes
    print(f"Price: {data['Close'][-1]}, Support level: {recent_lows}, Resistance level: {recent_highs}")
    time.sleep(500)
```

output

```
long
Price: 2530.699951171875, Support level: 2525.050048828125, Resistance level: 2534.199951171875
long
Price: 2530.75, Support level: 2525.050048828125, Resistance level: 2534.199951171875
long
Price: 2530.949951171875, Support level: 2525.050048828125, Resistance level: 2534.199951171875
long
Price: 2530.699951171875, Support level: 2525.050048828125, Resistance level: 2534.199951171875
long
Price: 2530.14990234375, Support level: 2525.050048828125, Resistance level: 2534.199951171875
long
Price: 2530.0, Support level: 2525.050048828125, Resistance level: 2534.199951171875
long
Price: 2530.14990234375, Support level: 2525.050048828125, Resistance level: 2534.199951171875
long
Price: 2530.0, Support level: 2525.050048828125, Resistance level: 2534.199951171875
long
Price: 2530.0, Support level: 2525.050048828125, Resistance level: 2534.199951171875
long
Price: 2530.0, Support level: 2525.050048828125, Resistance level: 2534.199951171875
long
Price: 2530.0, Support level: 2525.050048828125, Resistance level: 2534.199951171875
long
Price: 2530.050048828125, Support level: 2525.050048828125, Resistance level: 2534.199951171875
long
Price: 2530.0, Support level: 2525.050048828125, Resistance level: 2534.199951171875
long
Price: 2530.75, Support level: 2525.050048828125, Resistance level: 2534.199951171875
long
Price: 2530.64990234375, Support level: 2525.050048828125, Resistance level: 2534.199951171875
long
Price: 2530.64990234375, Support level: 2525.050048828125, Resistance level: 2534.199951171875
long
Price: 2530.300048828125, Support level: 2525.050048828125, Resistance level: 2534.199951171875
long
Price: 2531.0, Support level: 2525.050048828125, Resistance level: 2534.199951171875
long
Price: 2531.0, Support level: 2525.050048828125, Resistance level: 2534.199951171875
long
Price: 2531.0, Support level: 2525.050048828125, Resistance level: 2534.199951171875
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to read [ask] and then [edit] your question to give it a meaningful title, a clear [mre] including a description of what your code is supposed to do versus what it's actually doing, format the output so it's easily readable, and add appropriate tags.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see the code is doing exactly what you told it to. Maybe you should elaborate more on what is the problem.

Every 5 min it refreshes the price and support / resistance values as defined by your calculations.
Since the tested on interval always did fit your condition of being between support and resistance it does exactly what you told it to and recommends "long".
If you want to loop through different tickers instead of running for the same one every 5 min, consider placing a for loop over a list of tickers around your functional code.

Comment: please elobrate further